# How to list file entries based on first dropdown in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I would like to make two dropdowns in Jenkins where I can choose files at the first dropdown from a directory and the second dropdown should change based on the first dropdown (where the file has been selected) regarding the file content, these files have data in JSON format. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this using the [Active Choices plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) which allows you to populate the options for one parameter based on the value of another parameter.